# What is missing in the following steps to test db connection from eclipse using tomcat and java ?am getting 404 error

Tags: java, database, eclipse, testing, tomcat

```
My code to test db connection from eclipse is given below
```

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;

@WebServlet("/TestDbServlet")
public class TestDbServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String user="user01";
        String pass="pass01";
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
        String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
        
        // get connection to database
        try {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            
            out.println("Connecting to database: " + jdbcUrl);
            
            Class.forName(driver);
            
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass);
            
            out.println("SUCCESS!!!");
            
            myConn.close();
            
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException(exc);
        }

    }
```

am getting 404 error when i run this on server .I have added mysql-connector-java8.0.11.jar to lib folder of webinf.am using tomcat9 with java14 .

Comment: Can you post the error logged in catalina.out file under below directory ?$TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out

Comment: What URL are you using in your browser? By default it should be `http://localhost:8080/<Eclipse_project_name>/TestDbServlet`, where `<Eclipse_project_name>` is the name of your project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, if you are getting a 404 error it means that the page is not found (Probably if your url isn't correct), if there is an error in the doGet Method "The connection to the database part" the server will respond with a 500 error.

https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/solved-tomcat-error-http-status-404-not-found

Let me know if that helped.